# Variable division in or-tools python

Tags: python, or-tools, maximization, objective-function

I am working with **MIP solver** provided by **or-tools** (in python)

assume we have two variables **x** and **y** .
I know how to maximize one single variable OR the sum of two variables.

for example,
if we want to **maximize 2*x**  we can do it this way

```
objective = solver.Objective()
objective.SetCoefficient(x,2)
objective.SetMaximization()
```

and if we want to **maximize 2*x + 3*y**
we can do it this way

```
objective = solver.Objective()
objective.SetCoefficient(x,2)
objective.SetCoefficient(y,3)
objective.SetMaximization()
```

but waht I don't know is how to maximize a variable that is divided by another variable. my question is how to **maximize (x/y)** ?

Answer (score 3):

A MIP solver only accepts linear equations. By definition, division is not linear.
There can be very special cases when you can linearize division, for instance if y has a small set of possible values.

You can have a look at the CP-SAT solver, which proposes division, but cannot deal with continuous variables.